# How to grep a word thats four letters long and that starts with a certain letter

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to grep all words from /usr/share/dict/words that is four letters long and starts with "a".
For an example the result would be:

```
ally
area
arms
axes
etc..
```

It can be any length or any letter and I know how to do both individually I just cant figure out how to do it simultaneously. This is what I have so far.

```
grep -E -w -i "^[a]^[[:alnum:]]{4}" /usr/share/dict/words
```

but it obviously doesn't work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `^` twice like that. It can only match at the beginning. You don't need it again before `[[:alnum:]]`.

After matching the initial `a`, you should only match 3 additional letters, not 4.

You need to anchor the end with `$` so it doesn't match words longer than 4 characters. Or you can use the `-x` option to match the whole line.

I don't think there's any need to specify `[[:alnum:]]`. Everything in `/usr/share/dict/words` is alphanumeric, so you can simply match `.`.

```
grep -x -i '^a...' /usr/share/dict/words
```